# How do I save an MS Access Report as PDF/A (Archive version of PDF ISO 19005)

Tags: ms-access, pdf, vba

My client has asked that I output an MS-Access report as PDF/A  (Archive version of PDF ISO 19005). I've found an old thread from 2008 that says that it is possible to do this in Word, Excel, PPT, Publisher, Visio and Infopath but not Access. I'm hoping someone will have a recent update that this is now possible.

Currently my code is

```
 'output report to pdf
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, strReportName, acFormatPDF, strPDF, False, , , acExportQualityPrint
```

which works perfectly to create normal PDFs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a long shot and it's not elegant, but maybe could work for you:

Export the report as a regular pdf file and then through Word automation, open the file and export it as PDF/A.

Somehow the format is kind of messed up in the process, so keep it to the minimum in the access report.

```
Sub ExportPDF_A()

    ' Set references in VBA IDE to MS Word before executing this code

    ' Declare object variables
    Dim wordApp As New Word.Application
    Dim wordDoc As Word.Document

    ' Declare other variables
    Dim strReportName As String
    Dim strPDF As String

    ' Customize variables
    strReportName = "TableReport"
    strPDF = "E:\Temp\pdfreport.pdf"

    'output report to pdf
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, strReportName, acFormatPDF, strPDF, False, , , acExportQualityPrint

    ' Temporary set word visible (because there are some confirmation in the next step)
    wordApp.Visible = True

    ' Here are some additional confirmations that you'd have to figure out how to overcome them
    Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=strPDF, Format:="PDF Files", ConfirmConversions:=False)

    ' Export to the desired format
    wordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:="E:\Temp\pdfreportPDFA.pdf", ExportFormat:=WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=True, UseISO19005_1:=True


End Sub
```

I didn't spend a lot of time coding it so if this works, let me know and I can polish it.